# Chart.js: how to listen to hover/click events outside of plot area?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I create a bar chart that listens to hover and click events outside of the plot area?

Simple demo:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        onHover: () => console.log("hover"),
        onClick: () => console.log("click"),
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

As can be shown in the demo above, the hover and click callbacks do not get fired when the events happen outside of the plot area, e.g. when clicking axis tick labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom plugin with the `afterEvent` hook that will catch all events. In here you can filter out the events you want like `mousemove`, `mouseout`, `click` or any other event that gets thrown by interacting with the canvas.

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {},
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customEventListner',
    afterEvent: (chart, evt, opts) => {
      console.log(evt.event.type, evt.event.x, evt.event.y)
    }
  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```